# Given an adjacency list of a bidirectional graph, how to return a collection containing all possible paths from the root node of a certain length?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, graph, depth-first-search

I have an adjacency graph of nodes (in a bidirectional graph), and I was wondering how I would print all possible paths from the root of a certain length. As a result, repetition is allowed.
e.g., given the following graph

```
    1
   / \  
  2   3
 /     \
4       5
```

represented with the adjacency lists:

```
1 [2 3]  
2 [1 4]  
3 [1 5]  
4 [2]  
5 [3]
```

How would I return a collection of all paths from the root node of length 4? I'm looking to use Java, but just an algorithmic solution would help greatly. Some example of possible paths. The tree is not necessarily binary:

```
1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3  
1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 2  
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 3  
1 -> 3 -> 1 -> 3  
1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2  
1 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2
```

This would be represented as:

```
[1213,
1242,
1353,
1313,
1212,
1312]
```

I've been trying to apply some variation of the depth first search algorithm, but I'm not sure of how to keep track of the nodes.

Comment: There's a big difference between returning and printing, especially since recursion's involved.

Comment: sorry, clarified in the op.

Comment: Not really. the title still says "print" and the post says "return". Sidenote: your problem is basically how to keep track of paths. There are many examples of how to do that available.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), that tracks "How many nodes I have left" (remaining distance).

Each node recursively invoke DFS on all its neighbors, and when you reach the case where the number of nodes left is 0, stop and print the current path.

Pseudo code:

```
DFS(source, distance):
   List current = new LinkedList()
   DFS(source,distance,current)
DFS(source,distance,soFar):
   if (distance == 0): //stopping when distance is reached
      print (soFar + source) //never added the last node, doing it now
   else:
      soFar.append(source) 
      for each neighbour v of source:
         DFS(v,distance-1,soFar) //recursively call with shorter distance left
      soFar.removeLast() //remove the source that was added to the list
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "how many nodes I have left". In large graphs, I will not reach all the nodes, but rather all the nodes a set distance x edges from the root node.

Comment: He means distance/depth.

Comment: @keyser Clean up before ending the method, assuming soFar is a reference, you need to clean the element you added or you will just aggregate all elements of all paths, and not only elements in a single path.

Comment: Y that makes sense, backtracking. I don't know why I assumed they were passed as values.

Comment: I will implement your algorithmic solution and verify it works, thanks so much! just to clarify -  is source the root node, distance the distance away from the root specified? Additionally, the list SoFar holds the current path of one path, and not all, correct?

Comment: @NelsonLiu You shouldn't implement anything you don't understand. My tip would be that you run some DFS on small examples and print stuff in order to follow the flow of the program. Especially when starting out with recursion. In a short while the above source code will make perfect sense.

Comment: @NelsonLiu `source` is the root node (and changes recursively, but you start it with root node), `distance` is the distance specified, and `soFar` holds the current path up to now, in one single path.